# I want tor to use the same exit node

Tags: exit-relays

I really want to use the same exitnode each time I use TOR. I want the exitnode to be within the UK. I have just downloaded TOR therefore I'm new to how the setup works etc.

Comment: Why do you want the same exit node every time? There may be privacy implications you haven't thought of, or better solutions you don't know about.

Answer (score 3):

It's a very simple two-liner in your `torrc` config:

```
StrictNodes 1
ExitNodes {hash-id-of-your-desired-exit}
```

It works like that:

- [StrictNodes](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#StrictNodes) tells Tor that it **have to** obey the node restrictions you will impose in your config.
- [ExitNodes](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ExitNodes) specifies the comma-separated filters for your nodes. In your case - just one